# beautifulsoup doesn't grab the email but the format

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying different ways of getting the email address from here with this code:

```
email_pattern = 'a[href^=mailto]'
for email in soup.select(email_pattern):
  print(email)
```

However when doing this I get the whole code:

```
<a href="mailto:emailname61@yahoo.com?subject=?"><span class="ui_icon email _3ZW3afUk"></span><span class="_2saB_OSe">Email</span><span class="ui_icon external-link-no-box _2OpUzCuO"></span></a>
```

and I just want to get "emailname61@yahoo.com"

I've been trying with

```
email_pattern = 'a[href^=mailto]'
for email in soup.select(email_pattern.text):
  print(email)
```

and

```
email_pattern = 'a[href^=mailto]'
for email in soup.select(email_pattern):
      print(email.text)
```

But I just get the word email or nothing.

How can I get the email address?

Comment: `email['href']` ? And later you may have to remove `mailto:`

Answer (score 0):

Could you try

```
 email_pattern = r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)"
```

Answer (score 0):

This email is in attribute `href` so you have to get `email['href']`

And later you have to remove `mailto:` and `?subject=?`

---

Minimal working example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<a href="mailto:emailname61@yahoo.com?subject=?"><span class="ui_icon email _3ZW3afUk"></span><span class="_2saB_OSe">Email</span><span class="ui_icon external-link-no-box _2OpUzCuO"></span></a>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

email_pattern = 'a[href^=mailto]'
for email in soup.select(email_pattern):
    data = email['href']
    data = data.split('?')[0]  # remove `?subject=?`
    data = data.replace('mailto:', '')  # remove `mailto:`
    print(data)
```